# Python change boolean value

Tags: python, opencv, boolean

Im working on raspberi Pi 3. Im writing a code with opencv. Idea is to keep scanning for face until it finds it. If it does result.jpg needs to be send to email. But currently my send statement does not change from false to true. Face is detected no problem and i get resulting picture. But it just keeps looping the executeface(). How do I get send to change from False to true when facenumber is > 0.

```
#FOR FACE
import io
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy
import sched, time
import time
#FOR EMAIL
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

send=False

def sendresult():
    print "SENDING THE MAIL"

def executeface():
    print "starting execute face"
#Create a memory stream so photos doesn't need to be saved in a file
    stream = io.BytesIO()
#Get the picture (low resolution, so it should be quite fast)
#Here you can also specify other parameters (e.g.:rotate the image)
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (320, 240)
        camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
#Convert the picture into a numpy array
    buff = numpy.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
#Now creates an OpenCV image
    image = cv2.imdecode(buff, 1)
#Load a cascade file for detecting faces
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
#Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#Look for faces in the image using the loaded cascade file
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)
    print "Found "+str(len(faces))+" face(s)"
    facenumber = int(str(len(faces)))
    #print "send value ="+send

#Save the result image
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
    print "WROTE RESULT"
    return facenumber
    if facenumber > 0:
        send=True
        return send


while send is False:
    executeface()
    if send==True:
        print "execute sendresult"
        break
```

So my logic would be. executeface - if no face keeps scanning. If there is face change send=true and start sendresult, where results is emailed.

Comment: You return `send` but you never assign it to anything... Try `send = executeface()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work is you just repalce `send==True` with if `if executeface():`. You are returning the variable `facenumber` and the rest of the `executeface()` function never gets run. If `executeface()` returns 0 `if executeface()` will be `False` and otherwise `True`

Comment: thank you so much!! cant believe i missed simple thing as that! also send==true replaced with if executeface(): worked as a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if facenumber > 0` is never reached because you exit the executeface() function in the line before it ('return facenumber`).

Comment: Oh, and that too!